# How to prevent food shortage?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

Since several attempts I always run into the same problem: Food shortage.

What do you do to prevent such a food shortage?

*(I start with a [Microbe Musher](http://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Microbe_Musher) and try to build [Planter Boxes](http://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Planter_Box) as soon as possible. I never have more then 6 Dupes but I can't find enough seeds for it. Actually it always ends with a lack of Dirt or [Seeds](http://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Mealwood) and with starvation of my Dupes)*

Do you have any hints other then already known from the [Food Guide](http://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Guide/Food)?

Comment: Start with farming tech. Place 4 planters per dupe, plant mealwood, done. The only difficulty is getting enough seeds in the first place. IME this usually happens by just excavating the sandstone biome, provided that I'm not adding in dupes too fast. I tend to sit at 4 dupes for a long time before quickly surging up to 8 around cycles 50-100. The surge is fueled by the mealwood seeds dropped during prior harvests. If you have a shortage along the way, mush bars can deal with it, but it is totally feasible to avoid such a shortage.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't read the guide, but it is definitely worth while to have a dedicated chef that ONLY produces food. A dedicated chef with a single microbe musher is capable of producing enough food for 5 to 6 dupes I think. Supplement this with farms and you can keep a population of 10 to 13 with just two chefs and have good reserves when combined with refrigerators.

So pick a dupe with your highest cooking skill and disable all his other jobs / set the cooking stations to high priority.

Answer (score 2):

Playing the game since several months now, I would like to add the following informations:

If you start a new game, change the skills from one of your Dupes to a high as possible "Cooking" Value. This will reduce the time to get food from the Microbe Musher dramatically.

Set the "Pitcher Pump" (Liquid Bottler) as near as possible to your Microbe Musher or vice versa.

Set the Planter Boxes in the best possible environment (temperature, pressure) to decrease the time until you can harvest the plants or even get new seeds.

Don't forget to build additional Ration Boxes in ice cold bioms. This way you don't need power for refrigerators. And if you can redirect some CO2 to this area, your Ration Boxes can hold your precious food "forever", because of the "sterile (and cooler then 4°) atmosphere".